# A metric space in which every point is contained in a ball whose closure is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Suppose $X$ is a metric space such that for each $x\in X$, $\exists \epsilon_x>0$ such that $\overline{B(x,\epsilon_x)}$ is compact.Then show that this metric space is complete.

This is a problem from *Elements of Metric Spaces* by M.N. Mukherjee.But I think this problem is wrong.The statement is not true.Suppose $X=(0,1)$ with $(x,y)\mapsto |x-y|$ as metric.Then every $X$ satisfies the given property but is not a complete metric space.But,can this problem be modified to get some interesting results.

I am looking for some interesting properties of the metric spaces $X$ which satisfy the property,
**for each $x\in X$, $\exists \epsilon_x>0$ such that $\overline{B(x,\epsilon_x)}$ is compact.** Can someone give me some lead on this?

Comment: I suspect that the author used wrong order of quantifiers, it should be instead: There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $x\in X$ the closed ball $\bar{B}(x,\epsilon)$ is compact. Such spaces are complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your counterexample is just fine.

The spaces for which that property holds are locally compact. Therefore, by the Baire category theorem, it is a Baire space, that is, a space such that the intersection of countably many dense open sets is still dense.

Comment: In short, the space *is* completely metrisable.